# I have the error: “javac.exe” exited with code 3

Tags: java, android

I created a new project and try to build , but I have this error: “javac.exe” exited with code 3.
The output error is:

```
Creating C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Xamarin.Android\Cache\Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_28.apk

1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(417,2): warning : One or more errors occurred.

1>  App5.Android -> C:\Users\Пользователь\source\repos\App5\App5\App5.Android\bin\Debug\App5.Android.dll

1>  No way to resolve conflict between "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e". Choosing "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" arbitrarily.

1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2664,3): error MSB6006: "javac.exe" exited with code 3.

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========  
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple search for "android no way to resolve conflict between" revealed a forum post [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/79513/no-way-to-resolve-conflict-between-and-consider-app-config-remapping-of-assembly) that discusses the problem. Following links to the official [Xamarin bug report](https://xamarin.github.io/bugzilla-archives/44/44193/bug.html) reveals [the following solution](https://gist.github.com/dellis1972/001271bd681fa533c3cdedb5280d65e7):

Add this to your app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="B03F5F7F11D50A3A" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```